# Magento 2 - Show catalog product image changes on mouse over

Tags: magento2, product-images, listing

I would like to show product image changes on mouse over. I mean to call a second image during mouse over in **magento2**.

Comment: On catalog list page or in product page?

Comment: Hello
You did it?

Answer (score 0):

In your theme under

> app/design/frontend/themePackage/themeName/Magento_Theme/layout/

create **catalog_category_view.xml** (for category page) and/or **catalog_product_view.xml** (for product page) and/or **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** (for search result page) and add in this code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/your-script.js" />
        <css src="css/your-css.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Then you can create your-script.js file under

> app/design/frontend/themePackage/themeName/web/js/

and your-css.css under

> app/design/frontend/themePackage/themeName/web/css/

Now you can prepare your script to execute instructions on mouse over event.